# Using Mapster w/DI where should I be putting my mapping?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, mapster

Using Mapster with the Mapster DI package I also have a static class called MapperConfig that has a static method that does all my dto to viewmodel mapping.

```
 public static class MapperConfig
{
 public static void Config()
 {
   var tenantId = MapContext.Current.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("MySettings").GetValue<int>("DefaultTenantId");
   _ = TypeAdapterConfig<CountyDetail, CountyVM>.NewConfig()
            .Map(d => d.Phone.Number, s => string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(s.Phone.Number)))               
            .Map(d => d.Postal, s => s.Postal.Trim())
            .IgnoreNullValues(true);
  }
}
```

In the past I would call this in the ConfigureServices section of the startup class. Now I am trying to use DI with to pass some configuration values into the MapperConfig file so I have created an extension method:

```
  public static IServiceCollection AddMapster(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TypeAdapterConfig> options = null)
    {
        var config = TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings;
        config.Scan(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Startup)));
        options?.Invoke(config);
        services.AddSingleton(config);
        services.AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();
        return services;
    }
```

And then added that to my ConfigureServices section of the Startup class

```
  services.AddMapster(options =>
        {
            TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.IgnoreNullValues(true);
        });
```

Now if I leave the call to MapperConfig.Config in the Startup.ConfigureServices method Iget an error "Mapping must be called using ServiceAdapter".

Not sure how/where that would be done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `tenantId` needed to move into mapping configuration.

```
var tenantId = MapContext.Current.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("MySettings").GetValue<int>("DefaultTenantId");
```

For example:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<CountyDetail, CountyVM>.NewConfig()
     .Map(d => d.TenantId, 
          s => MapContext.Current.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("MySettings").GetValue<int>("DefaultTenantId"));
```

Comment: I don't see GetService method available in MapContext. Is it an extension method perhaps that I cannot find?

Comment: Found it. I had to reference Mapster.DependencyInjection.

Answer (score -1):

Put all of your custom mapping to TypeAdapterConfig, and register TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSetting as singleton.

```
services.AddSingleton(TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings);
services.AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();
```

Next, Register ServiceMapper to IMapper. Then you can inject IMapper to your constructor which need it.

```
public class SampleService 
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public SampleService(IMapper mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```